# How to use Logstash jdbc plugin to input for mutliple table joins of one to many relationships

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, one-to-many, elastic-stack

I have two tables linked in a one to many relationship , i.e for each row in first table there will be multiple rows in second table .
One employee can have many orders assigned to them .

ex : [image]

how can i achieve the data upload to elastic for a single index to have all orders in the form of an array of orders inside the main JSON source for that index?

Note that i want to achieve this purely with Logstash and Elastic , without handling this on app side or by using separate queries on application .

[image]

I also want to add that i have read about custom mappings and templates for elastic , but i need the logstash way of pushing data in the format i have shown.

Thanks !

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-jdbc-plugin-input-for-mutliple-table-joins-of-one-to-many-relationships/59933

Comment: Am also having the same requirement., is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to do a query that generates the output you want in JSON format for the multivalue field `orders`. An example with postgres would work like this:

First you would have an SQL query file `employees-logstash.sql` with something like:

```sql
WITH json_employee_orders as (
  select
    employee_id,
    JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('order_id', order_id, 'product_name', product_name) as orders
  from employee_orders
  group by employee_id
)

SELECT
  e.id, e.last_name, e.first_name, ...,
  jeo.orders::text as orders -- we use ::text because logstash doesn't recognize postgres native JSON type columns
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN json_employee_orders jeo ON jeo.employee_id = e.id
```

Then your employees-logstash.conf would have something like:

```yaml
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "${PWD}/postgresql-42.6.0.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}/${DATABASE_NAME}"
    jdbc_user => "${DATABASE_USER}"
    jdbc_password => "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
    statement_filepath => "${PWD}/employees-logstash.sql"
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "orders"
    target => "orders"
  }
}

output {
  opensearch {
    hosts => ["${OPENSEARCH_URL}"]
    user => "${OPENSEARCH_USER}"
    password => "${OPENSEARCH_PASSWORD}"
    index => "employees"
    document_id => "%{[id]}"
  }
}
```